# How to create a temporary table like other but without contraints

Tags: amazon-redshift, postgresql-8.4

In postgres 8 (redshift) how can i create a temporary table similar to what i have. But i don't want any constraints to be copied. this is what i do now

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_fbp_cats(LIKE cats);
```

But the null checks and other constrains are not required.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_fbp_cats AS SELECT * FROM cats LIMIT 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_fbp_cats AS LIKE cats;

Comment: This is not valid syntax. You might be getting confused between `CREATE TABLE AS` and `CREATE TABLE LIKE`.